# For Loop function only returning the same value

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a function that accepts a list (of integers) and an integer value and returns the number of elements in the list that are less than the given value. However, the code I have so far only ever returns 1 or 0 and I am not sure why. Can anyone help?

```py
def lesser_than(alist, value):
    """
    Returns:  number of elements in alist strictly less than value

    Example:  lesser_than([5, 9, 1, 7, 89], 6) evaluates to 2

    Parameter alist: the list to check (WHICH SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED)
    Precondition: alist is a list of ints

    Parameter value:  the value to compare to the list
    Precondition:  value is an int
    """
    ret = 0
    for a in alist:
        a = int(a)
        value = int(value)
        if a < value:
            ret += 1
        return ret
```

Comment: The `return` statement is in the `for` loop, it should probably be un-indented one level so it's after the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have your return in the for loop; it'll return as soon as the first entry is done. Remove a level of indentation on `return ret`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your return statement is in the for loop causing it to return at the first value less than the input. Move it outside the loop.

```
def lesser_than(alist,value):
    """
    Returns:  number of elements in alist strictly less than value

    Example:  lesser_than([5, 9, 1, 7, 89], 6) evaluates to 2

    Parameter alist: the list to check (WHICH SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED)
    Precondition: alist is a list of ints

    Parameter value:  the value to compare to the list
    Precondition:  value is an int
    """
    ret = 0
    value = int(value) #moved this outside the loop as it's only needed once
    for a in alist:
        a = int(a)
        if a < value:
            ret += 1
    return ret
```